# Is it possible to get a Stripe token using customer id in Stripe payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to retrieve Stripe token using customer id. I tried using the following method in PHP:

```
$num='cus_AkeyZp1eIsJHiI';
$customer=\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($num);
$customer=$customer->sources;
$customer=$customer->data;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the customer's credit card credentials for creating another customer account on Stripe use:

```
$token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
    "customer" => $num,
));
echo $token->id;
```

Here you created a token behalf of the customer's current card. You can now create a new customer with this token if you need.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => {CUSTOMER_EMAIL},
    "source" => $token->id
));
```

I don't think there is any way to retrieve the token you have created while creating the customer.

Or if you just need his attached card ID you could try :

```
$num='cus_AkeyZp1eIsJHiI';
$customer=\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($num);
$customer = $customer->__toArray(true);
print_r($customer['sources']['data']);
```

This will have the cards attached to the customer.